# If $f(x) $ and g(x) are functions such that $f(x+y) =f(x)g(y) +g(x) f(y) $ then ...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Question : 
If $f(x) $ and g(x) are functions such that $f(x+y) =f(x)g(y) +g(x) f(y) $ then $\begin{vmatrix}
f(\alpha) & g(\alpha) & f(\alpha + \theta) \\ f(\beta) & g(\beta) & f(\beta +\theta) \\ f(\gamma) & g(\gamma) & f(\gamma + \theta) \\
\end{vmatrix}$ is independent of

(a) $\alpha$

(b) $\beta$

(c) $\gamma$

(d) $\theta$

My approach  : Let x =0, y =0 the given equation becomes :

$f(0+0) = f(0) g(0) +g(0)f(0) $

$\Rightarrow f(0) =2f(0)g(0) $

$\Rightarrow f(0) \{ 1-2g(0)\} =0$

$\Rightarrow f(0) =0; g(0) =\frac{1}{2}$

Now assuming x=1, y=0

we get $f(1) =\frac{1}{2}$

But I dont know how to proceed further to get f(x) and g(x) please guide thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$f(\alpha + \theta) = g(\theta)f(\alpha) + f(\theta)g(\alpha), \tag{1}$

$f(\beta + \theta) = g(\theta)f(\beta) + f(\theta)g(\beta), \tag{2}$

$f(\gamma + \theta) = g(\theta)f(\gamma) + f(\theta)g(\gamma). \tag{3}$

(1)-(3) may be interpreted as asserting that the third column of

$\begin{vmatrix}
f(\alpha) & g(\alpha) & f(\alpha + \theta) \\ f(\beta) & g(\beta) & f(\beta +\theta) \\ f(\gamma) & g(\gamma) & f(\gamma + \theta) \\
\end{vmatrix} \tag{4}$

is a linear combination of the first two columns; as such, the determinant (4) vanishes for *all* values of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \theta$.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

We have $f(\alpha+\theta)=f(\alpha)g(\theta)+g(\alpha)f(\theta)$

Apply $$C_3'=C_3-[C_1\cdot g(\theta)+C_2\cdot f(\theta)]$$ where $C_i$ is the $i$th column $1\le i\le3$

Answer (score 0):

It is (d).

Since $f(\alpha+\theta)=f(\alpha)g(\theta)+f(\theta)g(\alpha)$,$f(\beta+\theta)=f(\beta)g(\theta)+f(\theta)g(\beta)$  and $f(\gamma +\theta)=f(\gamma)g(\theta)+f(\theta)g(\gamma)$,then it becomes

$\begin{vmatrix}
f(\alpha) & g(\alpha) & 0 \\ f(\beta) & g(\beta) & 0 \\ f(\gamma) & g(\gamma) & 0\\
\end{vmatrix}$

Comment: Since the last column is zero, the determinant is zero, so in particular it is independent of everything...no?

Comment: @user37238:  I & I say, "seen!"

Comment: Enn, o, yes, It is!

Comment: @RobertLewis I've seen your answer and I agree with it. My comment was for Paul.